# Dynamically add google places result in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have used google maps places to find nearby places.I can successfully get all the places that i want in the console window . But i cant add them dynamically to an dropdown box.For example:If you choose bank in the first dropdown you will get the name of bank in the console window, but i am unable to add the places in an new dropdown menu. Help me to do it

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <style>
              html, body, #map-canvas {
              height: 100%;
              }
            </style>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js'></script>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&libraries=places&geometry"></script>
            <script>
        var cityCircle;
    var marker;
    var markerEnd; 
    var map;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var myCenter;
    var markers = [];
    var markerEndArr = []; 
    var circles = [];
    var animationStatus=null;
    //google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var polylineOptionsActual = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor:"#008cff",
        strokeOpacity:0.8,
        strokeWeight:2,
    });
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        preserveViewport: true,
        polylineOptions: polylineOptionsActual,
         suppressMarkers: true,

        });

    function initialize() 
    {
      myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(13.0839, 80.2700);
      var options = {
        center:myCenter,
        //maxZoom: 15,
        zoom: 15,
      };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), options);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }


  function setPlaces()
  {
    directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    var placeType = document.getElementById('cmbMoreFunction').options[document.getElementById('cmbMoreFunction').selectedIndex].value;
    var kiloDistance=document.getElementById('kilometers').options[document.getElementById('kilometers').selectedIndex].value ;
    var request = {
        location:myCenter,
        radius: parseInt(kiloDistance),
        types: [placeType]
        };
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    var circleOptions = {
                      strokeColor:"#FF0040",
                      strokeOpacity:0.9,
                      strokeWeight:1,
                      fillColor:"#DF013A",
                      fillOpacity:0.2,        
                      map: map,
                      center: myCenter,
                      radius:parseInt(kiloDistance),
                    };

     service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

     function callback(results, status)
     {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            $("#placeResult").show()
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var k=results[i].vicinity;
                console.log(k)

                $("#fillResult").append("<option>"+results[0]+"</option>")
                }

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
                }

            for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                circles[i].setMap(null);
                }

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                place = results[i];
                if(calcDistance(results[i].geometry.location.lat () , results[i].geometry.location.lng ()) <= kiloDistance && place.name.toLowerCase() != placeType)
                {
                   createMarker(place,placeType );
                }
               }
            }
        }

    function stopAnimation()
    {
        if(animationStatus!=null)
        {
            animationStatus.setAnimation(null);
        }
     }


    function createMarker(place , placeType)
    {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: place.geometry.location,
        icon:placeType+'.png',
      });

        marker.setMap(map);


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

     var content = "<div class='infowindow-content'>"+"Place Name:"+ place.name+"<br>"+"<hr>" +"Distance From Center:"+(calcDistance(this.position.lat(),this.position.lng())/1000).toFixed(1)+"  "+"KM"+ "</div>" ;
     stopAnimation();
     animationStatus=this;
     this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

      var start = myCenter;
      var end = new google.maps.LatLng(this.position.lat(),this.position.lng());

      var request = {
       origin:start,
       destination:end,
       travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          }
        });

      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        if(infowindow)
        {
            infowindow.close()
        }
    });
       markers.push(marker);
       circles.push(cityCircle);
    }

    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);

    function calcDistance(placeLat , placeLon)
    { 
       return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myCenter, new google.maps.LatLng(placeLat , placeLon))
    }
  }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
          </head>
          <body onload="setPlaces()">
            <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 90%;float:left"></div>

            <div style="width: 10%; float:right">

            <select id="cmbMoreFunction" onchange="setPlaces()" >
                    <option value=""><------------></option>
                    <option value="atm">Atm</option>
                    <option value="bank">Banks</option>
                    <option value="gym">Gym</option>
                    <option value="hospital">Hospital</option>
                    <option value="library">Library</option>
                    <option value="park">Park</option>
                    <option value="pharmacy">Pharmacy</option>
                    <option value="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
                    <option value="school">Schools</option>
                    <option value="store">Stores</option>
                    <option value="bus_station">Bus Stop</option>
            </select>

            <select id="kilometers" onchange="setPlaces()">

                 <option value="1000">1 KM</option>
                 <option value="2000">2 KM</option>
                 <option value="3000">3 KM</option>
            </select>

            </div>
          <div id="placeResult" style="display: none">
            <select id="fillResult"></select>
          </div>

          </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$("#fillResult").append("<option>"+results[0]+"</option>")
```

should be:

```
$("#fillResult").append("<option>"+k+"</option>");
```

Note: the select will appears below the map, because the texts of the options are too large. When you want the select to appear beside the map you must restrict the `width` via CSS

---

Related to the comments(marker-animation):

First you need a reference to the marker. Add this to the end of the function createMarker:

```
return marker;
```

remove the loop where you currently add the options :

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   var k=results[i].vicinity;
   console.log(k)
   $("#fillResult").append("<option>"+k+"</option>")
   }
```

Modify the loop where you call  createMarkers:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        place = results[i];
        if(calcDistance(results[i].geometry.location.lat () , 
                        results[i].geometry.location.lng ()) 
             <= kiloDistance && place.name.toLowerCase() != placeType)
        {
           $("<option/>")
              .text(results[i].vicinity)
                .data('marker',createMarker(place,placeType ))
           .appendTo('#fillResult');

        }
       }
```

The reference to the marker is now stored inside the `<option/>`'s data.

Finally apply a change-listener to `#fillResult`(not within the loop, may be done in initialize) that triggers the mouseover for the marker(will have the same effect as if you hover the marker):

```
$("#fillResult").change(function(){
  google.maps.event.trigger($(this).find('option:selected').data('marker'),
                            'mouseover');
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! Am so stupid ! I didnt scroll down and see the result !

Comment: Don't worry, It also took some time for me until I recognized that

Comment: One more thing ! If i change the places from bank to another the drop down is not updated i have tried removing the element and adding new but that doesnot work

Comment: Yea i got that one too now !used $("#fillResult").remove(); Thanks :)

Comment: If select between the different places created in the dropdown dynamically.How to assign marker.bounce animation to it

Comment: still i am not getting the animation ! I think i am missing some thing !Can you give me an fiddle

Comment: Please create a fiddle based on your current code, I will help you to apply the modifications